# How can I cache an AngularJS directive that gets called repeatedly for the same user?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angular-directive

I have a user avatar directive that applies color to several paths in an SVG image per the user's preference. It gets applied to each comment in a thread that can be very long, and is compiled repeatedly for each user that has multiple comments.

Here's an abbreviated version:

```
angular.module('someModule')

.directive('userAvatar', ['$timeout', '$http', function ($timeout, $http) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/path/user-avatar.svg"></object>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.image = attrs.image;

            var init = function () {
                $timeout(function () {

                    var img = scope.image;
                    var path1, path2, path3;

                    // here we apply fill color to the paths by path ID
                }, 0);
            };

            var waitForRender = function () {
                if ($http.pendingRequests.length > 0) {
                    // wait for all templates to be loaded
                    $timeout(waitForRender); 
                } else {
                    init();
                }
            };

            $timeout(waitForRender);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Assuming that we can pass in a user ID for each comment, how might I cache the directive's output, which amounts to a styled SVG graphic, for each unique ID?

Answer (score 1):

`$cacheFactory` might do the job [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory).

Or `service` as singleton object also can be used for caching, since `service` unlike `controller` is not getting destroyed when view is gone.

**Based on your comment**, you might do following:

Create your custom cache factory. Be aware that this factory will be kind of persistent storage (until you close the window/tab)

```
angular.module('someModule').factory('superCache', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('super-cache');
}]
```

Then inject `superCache` into your directive. In your directive link function you can do something like:

```
var dataUsedInTemplate;
if(superCache.get(uniqueID)){
    // getting cached data if we already have it
    dataUsedInTemplate = superCache.get(uniqueID);
}else{
    // oops, we don't have data for this user yet, let's put it together
    dataUsedInTemplate = createUserSpecificTemplateData(uniqueID);

    // cache data for later use
    superCache.put(uniqueID, dataUsedInTemplate);
}
```

Comment: What is the data that you want to cache? `scope.image`? You can not store compiled template, it will be recompiled on each digest cycle.

Comment: It would be the object element from the template after styling had been applied to its child path elements.

Comment: I see... Please see updated answer. In case you need more help put your sample code into Plunker and share the link.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you want with CSS and [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). As others have suggested, if your calculations for which users get which Avatar colours are very complex or involve AJAX calls, you could store the values for quick retrieval in the future.

The code below has function that will do this: first it checks if the user "type" has already been calculated, and if it hasn't it goes ahead and calculates it.

Depending on the class of the SVG, it will have different colours that you set in the CSS. `Ng-include` will insert the SVG markup directly into the DOM, so you can manipulate it with CSS.

E.g.

**Markup:**

```
<ng-include class="avatar" 
    src="/path/user-avatar.svg" 
    ng-class="getUserType(user)"></ng-include>
```

**CSS:**

```
.avatar.type-a path1{
    fill: red;
}
.avatar.type-a path2{
    fill: white;
}
.avatar.type-a path3{
    fill: blue;
}

.avatar.type-b path1{
    fill: red;
}
.avatar.type-b path2{
    fill: green;
}
.avatar.type-b path3{
    fill: yellow;
}
```

**JS:**

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){

   $scope.getUserType = function(user){
       // Don't recalculate the class for this user if you've already done it
       if(typeof user.type !== 'undefined'){
           return user.type;
       }
       // This is where your logic goes if you need to calculate the user type
       else if(user.ID == 1){
           user.type = 'type-a';
       }
       else{
           user.type = 'type-b';
       }
       return user.type;
   }

}]);
```

Comment: Is `currentColor` pseudo-code, or where does it come from?

Comment: `currentColor` is not pseudocode - it'll apply whatever the current `color` style is to the rule in question. In this case it would make the `fill` inherit the same value as `color`. See here for a better explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword

Comment: I see. How would I apply 3 different colors to 3 different paths in a user's avatar with this approach?

Comment: Instead of using style, you could use ng-class.
**Markup:**

    <ng-include class="avatar" 
        src="/path/user-avatar.svg" 
        style="color: {{user.color}}"></ng-include>


**CSS:**

    .avatar path1{
        fill: currentColor;
    }

Comment: Sorry, pressed return too quickly and can't delete the comment before. You could use ng-class instead of style. E.g. `ng-class=""`

Comment: I see now. Problem is, users could potentially select any of millions of color combinations. I wouldn't be able to create CSS rules for all of them. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way you'd do with any JavaScript library. Create an object, stash it as a value with your parameter as a key. Then, when you need it, see if it's in there and use it instead of regenerating.

```
var cache = {};

link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // ...
    var id = getUserIdSomehow();

    if (!cache[id]) {
        cache[id] = createNewImage(id);
    }

    return cache[id];
    // ...
}
```

Not exact code obviously, just pseudo-code for illustration. Basically, have a variable, either in scope or at a global level (depending on your exact use-case), and just store created images in it so you only create them if you don't already have one.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I had in mind, but I'm unclear as to how to compile the directive template and store it. Would you mind enhancing your answer to address that step?

Comment: Also, where does `cache` exist? I experimented with something similar using `$rootScope`. Obviously it needs to exist outside the directive's child scope.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look close enough at your example code. I didn't realize your directive also had the template of the svg directly. You'll probably want to cache it as part of a different directive, and then use that to display the SVG (it'd basically have a template of `<div>{vm.userAvatar}</div>` and treat the SVG itself as a variable, not a component.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a service that manages a user's settings. That way you can modify the implementation in the future as necessary without having to touch your directive. You may want to store this in a database or on [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) if this setting doesn't need to persist indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd need a bit more detail to understand your suggestion, though. In this case, there are comments being loaded that aren't associated with the currently-authenticated user.